# clarification on spring mvc ModelMap

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
public String addStudent( @ModelAttribute("HelloWeb")Student student, ModelMap model){
}
```

can somebody explain how does this work?

what is the use of `ModelMap model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An architecture pattern followed in web applications is MVC which stands for Model, View And Controller.
Model holds the data. View is your display and Controller controls the flow.

A model is generally a simple object which can be rendered on screen. For example, a simple update user preferences will hold data which can be contained in a domain or model object called as user.

However, when the views and interactions get complex, a simple object may not suffice. And a complex object is needed. This somewhat complex object contains some other objects. For example, a page like user's news feed dashboard may have to hold data about;

1. user (name, etc) held in some user object
2. user's preferences held in userpreference object which in turn can be part of user
3. Some other objects - which may are not very suitable to be contained in the user object itself.

Basically, all these objects can make the model somewhat complex. So for better organization, these can be stored as name value pairs and packaged inside a single Map. So the page can refer to the required keys and get the object it needs to render.

ModelMap is this kind of a container object

Answer (score 4):

`ModelMap` subclasses `LinkedHashMap`.

```
public class ModelMap extends LinkedHashMap{

}
```

`Model` is an interface. `ModelMap` is an implementation of the `Model interface`.

Basically when you have data in code and you want to make that data available to the rendering of your `jsp` page, you need to put that data somewhere so that it is available. That is what a `Model` is for. To hold that data you retrieved in your code. It is just a glorified map.

So example, I have a form with a backing object with data. The form has three drop downs that I also need data to fill the drop downs. That is 4 different objects. 3 Lists for the drop downs and one object for the form backing object.
If my code gets all this data, I put them into the `Model`'s Map and now I can use them on my `jsp` page.

refer [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) for more info.

also refer [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/08/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and.html) for detailed info.